# Cache-Control with next js and custom server in ssr pages

Tags: next.js, server, cache-control

i have a next js app that for api calls "api route" of its own, but in some testing find out my cache-control not works and in each request it hits api route, what's the issue:
my landing:

```
const HomePage = ({ res }: { res: Response<HomeResponse> }) => {
  return <div>
  </div>
}

export default HomePage;
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({ res }) => {
//axios api call in here
let call = await axios.get("/api/landing")
  res.setHeader(
                'Cache-Control',
                `public, s-maxage=60, stale-while-revalidate=120`
            );
return {
props: { res: call.data }
}
}
```

and my api route have cache-controls too but my log in it shows up in every request even so i run it with npm run start that uses build verion of app(i read somewhere it not works in dev)?
this is my custom server:

```
const { createServer } = require("http");
const { parse } = require("url");
const next = require("next");

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development";
const hostname = "localhost";
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
// when using middleware `hostname` and `port` must be provided below
const app = next({ dev, hostname, port });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();
app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer(async (req, res) => {
    try {
      // Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to `url.parse`.
      // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
      const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
      const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl;
      if (pathname.startsWith("/fonts") ||
        pathname.startsWith("/img") ||
        pathname.startsWith("/static") ||
        pathname.startsWith("/widgets")) {
        res.setHeader(
          'Cache-Control',
          'public,max-age=31536000,immutable'
        )
      }
      if (pathname === "/a") {
        await app.render(req, res, "/a", query);
      } else if (pathname === "/b") {
        await app.render(req, res, "/b", query);
      } else {
        //if (res.getHeader('Cache-Control'))
          console.log("===", parsedUrl, res.getHeaders())
        await handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Error occurred handling", req.url, err);
      res.statusCode = 500;
      res.end("internal server error");
    }
  }).listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`> Ready on http://${hostname}:${port}`);
  });
});
```

im using next js "^13.1.6" and host my app on windows with iis node and web.config like this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- Visit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/11/14/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx for more information on WebSocket support -->
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
        </rule> -->
        <rule name="ignore" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="/test*" />
          <action type="None" />
        </rule>
        <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <!--First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule> -->

        <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <add segment="node_modules"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
    <iisnode node_env="production" nodeProcessCommandLine="C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" />
    <!--
      You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options:
        * watchedFiles: semi-colon separated list of files that will be watched for changes to restart the server
        * node_env: will be propagated to node as NODE_ENV environment variable
        * debuggingEnabled - controls whether the built-in debugger is enabled
      See https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config for a full list of options
    -->
    <!--<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>-->
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="Deny" />
          <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block" />
          <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
          <add name="Referrer-Policy" value="strict-origin-when-cross-origin" />
          <add name="X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies" value="none" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT" />
          <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
          <remove name="Server" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```